# Parse JSON data into Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am trying to resolve a problem I'm stuck at.
 My project database assigns one `parentId` to every parent who can have multiple `childId` for their children.
After login, iOS App should display all  `childId` associated with `parentId`.
My Database:

```
ParentID    ChildID    Name        Class
   10          45       Andrew        4
   10          46       Sarah         8
   11          47       Mark          2
   12          48       Claire        4
```

I've managed to create a JSON string for this information, if `parentId` is inserted into a PHP form, for parentId =10:

```
[{"childId":45,"name":"Andrew","class":"4"},{"childId":46,"name":"Sarah","class":"8"}]}
```

**However I'm not good at parsing this data into our iOS app so that a parent can see their children ids**

My Swift Code so far, obviously it's not helping! (Im using Alamofire for my iOS networking)

```
let URL_CHILD_DEVICE = "http://localhost/test/dashDevice.php"

//the defaultvalues to store data
let defaultValues = UserDefaults.standard

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if let name = defaultValues.string(forKey: "parentId") {
        labelParentId.text = pname
    }
    Alamofire.request(URL_CHILD_DEVICE, method: .get).responseJSON {
        response in
        if response.data != nil {
            let json = JSON(data: response.data!)
            let name = json["name"][0]["class"].string
            if name != nil {
                print(name!)
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Use [`Codable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types)

Answer (score 0):

This is really simple with the `Codable` protocol (see more info [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/codable)). First, you need to create a struct representing your model:

```
struct Person: Codable {
    let parentId: Int  // Or String. Not sure from your data.
    let childId: Int
    let name: String
    let `class`: Int  // This could be an enum.
}
```

Conforming to `Codable` will allow the compiler to generate the encoding/decoding methods you need to parse the JSON. All that's left is to attempt to parse it in your network response.

```
Alamofire.request(URL_CHILD_DEVICE, method: .get).responseJSON { response in
    if let data = response.data {
        do {
            let person = try JSONDecoder().decode(Person.self, from: data)
            print(person.name)
        } catch {
            // handle errors
        }
    }
}
```